# How to use bootstrap js files with angular-meteor

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, angular, angular-meteor

I am trying to use bootstrap js features following the [angular-meteor tutorial](https://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular2/css-sass-and-bootstrap)
In that tutorial(see link) they have integrated bootstrap sass files. But how do I integrate the bootstrap.js file?

I tried using

```
import { bootstrap } from 'bootstrap';
```

In the main.ts file, but this is not working(IDE shows cannot resolve file bootstrap).
Surprisingly, my node_modules has the bootstrap package installed(the boostrap.sass gets imported successfully). Here is how my node_modules look like:

[image]

So how do I import this bootstrap.js file?

EDIT: Things I further tried are:

1. `import bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'` does not work and gives error "Cannot find module 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'"
2. `import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'` works but this demands that tether be added as dependency. I added tether via npm and then added it(`import 'tether/dist/js/tether'`) before above import in main.ts but this too does not solve the problem browser console says:

> bootstrap.js:2785 Uncaught Error: Bootstrap tooltips require Tether
>   (http://github.hubspot.com/tether/)

Comment: You use angular2-meteor with the angularJS (1) version of the tutorial?

Comment: From your import statement it looks like you assume there to be an index.js in `node-modules/bootstrap`. If you were going to import something, it would have to be something like `import { bootstrap } from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap';`. This assumes that the bootstrap.js file is exporting something called "bootstrap", which I can almost certainly guarantee it isn't. You would have to look to make sure, though.

Comment: @CodeChimp you seem to be correct. I simply want to use the bootstrap.js file here. Thats why I am trying to include it in main.ts file. I even tried `import bootstrap from 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'` but this still does not work. `import 'bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap'` works but demands tether. Check out edit to get what error I get here

Comment: #1 fails because the bootstrap.js code doesn't export anything called "bootstrap". I would totally expect that. #2 looks more promising, and most likely it's due to bootstrap requiring the tether library but it couldn't find it. You should be able to provide that somehow, maybe by adding the module through NPM, and get past that error.

Comment: @CodeChimp I have already tried adding tether via npm install tether and its even in node_modules. Also I am importing tether before bootstrap js(in #2) . Still the console shows bootstrap requires tether error.